# Scala Enum to Map [cannot prove ...]

Tags: scala, enums, hashmap

I have this enum :

```
object PhsIndType extends Enumeration{
  type PhsIndType = Value
  val A : Value = Value(1)
  val R : Value= Value(2)
  val O : Value = Value(3)
  val E : Value = Value(4)
}
```

And i'm trying to load it into a map for easier use :

```
    val map = PhsIndType.values.toMap[AnyVal, AnyVal]
```

I've tried using every type I could think of instead of AnyVal, but I always get the error :

```
Cannot prove that enumeration.PhsIndType.Value <:< (AnyVal, AnyVal).
val map = PhsIndType.values.toMap[AnyVal, AnyVal]
```

Anyone has a fix ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `toMap` is:

```
toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U]
```

That means that the underlying collection needs to have element of type `Tuple2`.

The type of `PhsIndType.values` is `PhsIndType.ValueSet` and not of type `Tuple2`

To achieve the desired result you want, you need to convert the underlying collection into type of `(T,U)` or `Tuple2` and you can this by mapping:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

  object PhsIndType extends Enumeration {
    type PhsIndType = Value
    val A : Value = Value(1)
    val R : Value= Value(2)
    val O : Value = Value(3)
    val E : Value = Value(4)
  }

  PhsIndType.values.map(x => (x.id, x)).toMap


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object PhsIndType
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,PhsIndType.Value] = Map(1 -> A, 2 -> R, 3 -> O, 4 -> E)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toMap`

```
PhsIndType.values.map(x => x -> x.id).toMap
```

Type of the resultant map can be `Map[PhsIndType.Value,Int]`. You don't need to have `Map[AnyVal, AnyVal]`

## Scala REPL

```
scala> PhsIndType.values.map(x => x -> x.id).toMap
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Map[PhsIndType.Value,Int] = Map(A -> 1, R -> 2, O -> 3, E -> 4)
```